# Calling a html control from php code

Tags: php

I have a label control on my page, whose visibility is false.

I want that if a certain event occurs, its visibility becomes true, as the event is ha.dled through php code. How do I specify an HTML element's id(`<Label id="ThnxLabel">Thank You</Label>`) in the php code?

Comment: Your page is already loaded, if you want to change the label dynamically, have a look at AJAX and change the label after an AJAX-Request using JavaScript. Otherwise, you have to reload the whole page.

Comment: I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding here. PHP cannot "call an HTML control". If you want to dynamically modify things in the browser, you'll have to do it client-side using Javascript.

Comment: It is client-side, so you have to use Javascript, not PHP.

Comment: Yea, am very new to php. I have learned asp.net, So i mix thngs.

Comment: Hows this possible, that you cannot get your controls id in php code..

Comment: can i use java script inside a php code...

Comment: PHP runs on the server; when it's over, it sends output to the browser. Once on the browser, javascript can do its work; basically, when javascript is loaded, PHP has long finished it's job. To get form values in php you need to send the request to the server, so that php can process it and give back the results; and yes, you can get form content with php, you just need another request (or, client-side, with AJAX, which sends an http request "In background" and held by javascript)

Comment: And that's why learning using a very high-level framework is not good. :) PHP is very close to the bare metal, where you cannot call anything from the server to the client. .NET has a lot of abstractions that give the programmer the impression such things are possible, but behind the scenes they actually aren't. It's just clever abstractions and packaging of common functionality.

Answer (score 2):

No matter what your backend language, all web pages end up as HTML for layout and content, CSS for display properties for that content, and optionally Javascript for any dynamic behavior once the page is downloaded by the browser.

PHP, Ruby, C#, whatever - they all spit out those 3 things.  To be a web developer is to understand how HTML+CSS+JS work, and then to understand how your server-side language generates those 3 things.

In PHP or any language, you'd output some HTML like so:

```
<div id="some-id">This is text I want to show</div>
```

And in your CSS file you'd have:

```
#some-id { display: none; }
```

Which would result in a page that when downloaded and rendered in a browser contains a DIV with text that's hidden.  To make it visible when the user clicks something, you'd use jQuery or similar javascript language to attach an event handler like so:

```
$('#some-id')        // Grab the div
  .click(            // Add a click handler
    function() {     // Create a one time use function for the handler to call
      $(this).show();// Show the div
    }
  );
```

Client-side code is always in Javascript.  Server-side code can be in one of many different languages.  Your .NET experience has given you the wrong idea about how the web works, but it's not too late!  :-)  Good luck with it.